# What does `== s` mean when subsetting data?

Tags: r

My question involves summarizing a data frame where I am supposed to delete all empty cases. I tried using `na.rm`, but didn't work because the rows without value actually is written "**not available**", then I was getting an error due to missing data. 
Looking around what I could do I came across a script where the person select the lines using the following command:

```
filtered <- x[x$State==s & 
  x$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack != 'Not Available', 
    c("Hospital.Name","Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack")]
```

I fixed the issue of how to select the "**not available**", but I didn't understand what the `==s` does. Can anyone explain it to me please?

Comment: More generally: `==` is a test for equivalency. `2 == 2` returns `TRUE`, as does `4/2 == 2`. This distinguishes it from a single equal sign `=` which in many programming languages (including R) is an assignment operator (basically, an alternative to `<-`, but in R you should keep using `<-`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things here:

- your subsetting operation is doing three things at once:

  - selecting all rows where the `State` variable is equal to the value stored in the variable `s` (which must have been set before this line was run; otherwise you'd get an error); this is the meaning of `x$State == s` ...
  - **and** (this is what the `&` operator means) the Hospital-30-day-mortality-rates variable is not missing
  - **and** selecting just the hospital name and mortality-rate columns from the data set (this is what the bit after the `,` is doing)
- If you are reading the data in from a file using `read.csv()` or `read.table()`, you could use the `na.strings` argument to specify that "Not Available" should automatically get transformed to R's missing value, `NA`
- you might want to rename your long-named variable (there are handy renaming functions in the `gdata`, `sjmisc`, `plyr`, and `dplyr` packages: pick one)
- you can also use `subset` from base R, or `filter` and `select` from `dplyr`, to perform these operations

Comment: for what it's worth, StackOverflow prefers that you *not* use comments to say "thank you"; instead, if the posted answer solves your problem, you can click on the check-mark to accept it.